# Comparing attribute of an object in implementation of priority queue

Tags: java, priority-queue

I've attempted to implement a priority queue using an Array of Objects "Queue Items" which have some data (a string), and an integer which is the priority. I am trying to make those items comparable so that when I add a new object to the queue I can iterate through the items and add the new item in the correct location and move all items that are now behind it backwards, however when I add a new item to the queue I get a null pointer exception. I'll include all my code, but the toString method was just copied in from a queue so it won't work as expected.

```
class QueueItem implements Comparable<QueueItem> {
    String data;
    int pri;

    public QueueItem(String data, int pri) {
        this.data = data;
        this.pri = pri;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(QueueItem item) {
        return this.data.compareTo(item.data);
    }
}

public class PriorityQueue implements Queue<String> {
    private QueueItem[] arr;
    private int frontPos, backPos;

    public PriorityQueue() {
        arr = new QueueItem[20];
        backPos = -1;
        frontPos = 0;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return frontPos == (backPos + 1) % arr.length;
    }

    public String front() {
        if (frontPos == (backPos + 1) % arr.length)
            throw new QueueException("Empty Queue - front");
        return arr[frontPos].data;
    }

    public int frontPri() {
        if (frontPos == (backPos + 1) % arr.length)
            throw new QueueException("Empty Queue - frontPri");
        return arr[frontPos].pri;
    }

    public void addToPQ(String str, int x) {
        if (arr.length==0) {
            arr[frontPos] = new QueueItem(str, x);
            frontPos++;
            return;
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                arr[i].compareTo(new QueueItem(str, x));
            }
        }
    }

    public void deleteFront() {
        if (frontPos==(backPos+1)%arr.length) {
            throw new QueueException("Empty Queue - deleteFront");
        }
        frontPos = (frontPos+1)%arr.length;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (frontPos == (backPos + 1) % arr.length) {
            return "<>";
        }
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        sb.append('<');

        int pos = frontPos;
        while (pos != backPos) {
            sb.append(arr[pos]);
            sb.append(',');
            pos = (pos + 1) % arr.length;
        }

        sb.append(arr[backPos]);
        sb.append('>');

        return (sb.toString());
    }
}

public interface Queue<String> {
    public void addToPQ(String str, int x);

    public void deleteFront();

    public String front();

    public boolean isEmpty();

    public int frontPri();
}

class QueueException extends RuntimeException {
    QueueException(String s) {
        super("Tried to apply " + s + " to empty queue");
    }
}

public class pqTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue pQ = new PriorityQueue();
        if (pQ.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Queue is Empty - isEmpty");
        }
        pQ.addToPQ("Dog", 4);
        pQ.addToPQ("Cat", 20);
        pQ.deleteFront();
        pQ.addToPQ("Fish", 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: why not use java.util.priorityqueue?

Comment: you are using `arr.length == 0` to determine if your queue is empty. Yet your queue is initialized with size 20. Use a debugger to find the nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `arr` is size 20 so the first element won't even be added through the if statement in your `addToPQ` method because `arr.length != 0`. So it will then go to your else statement, which iterates through every single element in `arr`. But `arr` has 20 null elements since each spot within the array of QueueItems has not been initialized. So you should change your condition in the if statement to `frontPos == 0` and change the terminating condition in your loop to `i < frontPos` so that the method won't iterate through null elements within `arr`

```
public void addToPQ(String str, int x) {
        if (frontPos==0) {
            arr[frontPos] = new QueueItem(str, x);
            frontPos++;
            return;
        }
        else {
            QueueItem item = new QueueItem(str, x);
            for (int i = 0; i < frontPos; i++) {
                arr[i].compareTo(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That now works for handling the first item, now when I add a second item to the queue I get an OutOfMemoryError and it says cannot find local variable 'str'?

Comment: @Chaz check my edit. I believe it was because u had `arr[i].compareTo(new QueueItem(str, x))` which is really inefficient because you're unnecessarily creating the same object multiple times. So what I did was make the new item once outside of the loop so that the loop can run efficiently when comparing to the new item.

Answer (score 0):

You get NullPointerException, because when you are adding second item, you go to else statment where you iterate over array with one non-null element and 19 nulls. So you need to change your code to check if array element at **i** is null and if it is, assign new element to it.

Comment: no, it's already when adding the first element. Just debugged it.